# HttpURLConnection onclick

Tags: java

Добрый день!

Есть кнопка:

```
<span class="surf_ckick" onclick="start_surfing('viewing_surfing?id=287606', '287606'); this.style.textDecoration='line-through'; this.style.color='#FF3800'; ">Меняем время на деньги!Без вложений</span>
```

Как мне произвести на неё нажатие через `HttpURLConnection`?

Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нажмите на эту кнопку в браузере, и, с помощью сниффера посмотрите, какой запрос выполняется при этом нажатии. Имея информацию о запросе, его можно воспроизвести с помощью `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Как сделать сниффер ?

Comment: @as1andrey1, Его не надо делать. Можно воспользоваться простым аддоном к браузеру, например, Live HTTP Headers (для [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo), для [FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/)). Для более сложных задач можно воспользоваться чем-нибудь вроде Wireshark.